# Internet Explorer 8 and below issues

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I'm not sure where to even begin to fix this myself, so I am hoping someone here has or understand browser compatibility and can assist me in this.  Please see jsFiddle.net example for all of my code.

[jsFiddle.net example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesjw007/kfrjd/1/)

I run this code on my live machine in Firefox 11+ and it works fantastic.  I run the same code in Internet Explorer 9 and it runs fantastic.  I switch the Document Mode to IE8 and it begins to fail.

Here are some images to show what I am talking about:

Also in IE7 the logo is pushed way down see IE7 example.  This works in Safari also, image not supplied.

IE9 [image: IE9]
IE8 [image: IE8]
IE7 [image: IE7]
FF11+ [image: FF11+]

Comment: well maybe you can tell us what failed. the images are make no sense

Comment: I'm not sure how the images do not make sense, but I will explain in text.  IE7 the hover over menu does not work (as visable in IE7 image) also the logo is pushed way down.  In IE8 the logo is correct, but the hover over menu does not work.  In IE9 it works and the logo is correct and the images show.  In FF11+ it shows it as working correctly as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kfrjd/2/).  The issue appears to be that your `:first` selector isn't working in IE8.  I'm not sure why you would need the `:first` selector as there is only one `ul` below each menu item, but maybe I missed something.  If you remove the `:first` selector it works fine.

Comment: I see now that that wasn't needed, that made it work in IE7+.  The only issue left now is the logo is pushed way far down (seen in IE7 image) any idea about that?

Answer (score 2):

your second problem : logo

look here 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kfrjd/18/)

put div id=content before span clear-both, ie has problem with that

Comment: since I got the checkmark, I figured I'd vote you up for part 2 :)

Comment: I couldn't give it to both of you or I would have. =( @PatrickKlingemann